# Tooltip pointer in ParametricPlots

Tags: plotting, tooltip

```
ParametricPlot[{ Cos[u]^v , u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2 }, Mesh -> {5, 5}]

ParametricPlot[Tootip[{ Cos[u]^v , u}, {v, 0, 1}], {u, 0, Pi/2 }]
```

How to introduce Tooltip pointers?

( ParametricPlot3D Tooltip may not be available yet? ).

EDIT1:

Updating my question. Please ignore everything above the EDIT1:

```
ParametricPlot[ { u Cos[v], u Sin[v]}, {u, 1, 2}, {v, 0, Pi/2}, 
 Mesh -> {3, 5}]
```

It is a *two* parameter plot. So I like to see *either* of $ u,v $ parameter lines being pointed at with the value of the set constant only.

To make clear with an example, when I mouse over circles, like to see Tooltips in the above ParametricPlot pointing with *SINGLE* values {$ 1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2 $} *and also* when mousing over radial lines  *SINGLE* {$ 0, \pi/12, 2 \pi/12,...5 \pi/12, \pi/2 $ }  for the radial lines.

It is a very simple requirement that I believe could cater to a common requirement of a majority of users. I am not looking at high frequency sophisticated dynamic motion picture display. Not even looking at double parameter display at intersection/junction  of parameter lines. Just like the way height is displayed for ContourPlots. Here it is required for both parameters, with or without Shading.

Asked this because it is not (yet) a standard feature.

EDIT2:

Based on Michael E2's lines, tried to depict eccentric circles.In the space  between parameter lines it may need to be somewhat changed.

```
{umin, umax, ustep, vmin, vmax, vstep} = {0, 2 Pi, Pi/8, 0.25, 1.25, .25};
ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[2 + v^2] + v Cos[u], v Sin[u]}, {u, umin,  umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}, Mesh -> {Table[{u, Tooltip[Null, u]}, {u, umin, umax, ustep}], 
    Table[{v, Tooltip[Null, v]}, {v, vmin, vmax, vstep}]}] /. {g___, 
   Tooltip[_, label_], l_Line} :> {g, Tooltip[l, label]}
```

Comment: ParametricPlot[Table[Tooltip[{u Cos[v], u Sin[v]}], {v, 0, Pi/2, Pi/20}], {u, .5, 
  1}, Evaluated -> True].                                                                                Is it possible to see pointing for both parameters, u and v?

Comment: There are several syntax errors: the correct spelling is `Tooltip` and only `{ Cos[u]^v , u}` must be wrapped in in, not `{ Cos[u]^v , u}, {v,0,1}`.  Then it works (both v10 and v10.1)

Comment: @Szabolcs  The OP wants the values of  `{v, u}` displayed, not the symbolic expressions `{Cos[u]^v, u}`.  Furthermore, he appears to want those values displayed only at mesh points.  `ListPlot[Quiet@
  Tooltip[Table[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {v, 0, 1, .2}, {u, 0, Pi/2, Pi/12}]], 
 PlotStyle -> Black]` gives the values of `{Cos[u]^v, u}`, but not of `{v, u}`.  I have been playing with `MousePosition`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey (To the OP) It's not a very well phrased question, so it's really hard to see what you are looking for ... such an essential detail should be clearly written in the question itself, not in a comment under one of the answers.  This is what I'd do: right clicking the plot and choosing "Get Coordinates" shows the plot coordinates $(x,y)$ when moving the mouse.  The `CoordinatesToolOptions` option controls what is displayed precisely.  If the $(u,v) \leftrightarrow (x,y)$ mapping is invertible, you can transform $(x,y)$ back to $(u,v)$ and display them.

Comment: This will show the values everywhere, not only at mesh points.  It's still not very clear to me whether you want (1) tooltips *only* in mesh points or (2) tooltips at any coordinate.  Please clarify this in the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs  What an instructive comment.  I did not know that "Get Coordinates".existed, much less that it and other capabilities could be modified by `CoordinatesToolOptions`.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a dummy graphic to each mesh line with the appropriate tooltip label and combine them via post-processing:

```
ParametricPlot[{u Cos[v], u Sin[v]}, {u, 1, 2}, {v, 0, Pi/2},
  Mesh -> {
    Table[{u, Tooltip[Null, u]}, {u, 1, 2, 0.25}],
    Table[{v, Tooltip[Null, v]}, {v, 0, Pi/2, Pi/12}]}
  ] /. {g___, Tooltip[_, label_], l__Line} :> {g, Tooltip[{l}, label]}
```

Update notice: The pattern was changed from `l_Line` to `l__Line` to handle multiple instances of `Line` in a mesh line, as pointed out by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) in a comment, along with a change in the `Tooltip` code to handle the sequence `l`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to see... Next I tried on this basis to make only first two lines as variable in code where I put in the parameter start,end, increment values as given in EDIT2:.But still there is a small problem (Null is not Graphics directive..)  Null, Disk, these do not work.

Comment: @Narasimham There can be more than one `Line` following the `Tooltip` in the generated expression.  Use this replacement rule instead:  `{g___, Tooltip[_, label_], l__Line} :> {g, Tooltip[{l}, label]}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It works! ( I was referring to the 2 lines at program start)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A much more versatile "do-it-yourself" tooltip can be achieved from

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, Mesh -> {5, 5},
  FrameLabel -> {Cos[u]^v, u}, ImagePadding -> {{60, 90}, {40, 10}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style[Dynamic[{Log[First@mouse]/Log[Cos[Last@mouse]], 
       Last@mouse}], "TooltipLabel"], FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False], 
     Dynamic[mouse = MousePosition["Graphics", {.01, .01}]; 
       mouse = {Clip[First@mouse, {0, 1}], Last@mouse}], {-1., -1.}]]
```

It displays `{v, u}`.

Comment: Does it display (u,v) on parameter curves?

Comment: @Narasimham  It displays `{v, u}` everywhere in the region, `{v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2}`.

Comment: @Narasimham   I corrected a typo (`Framed@` in front of the wrong instance of `Dynamic`) a few minutes ago.  So, if you encountered problems, try again with the corrected version.

Comment: It is alright. However, I need display of (u,v) values at default or chosen mesh parameter values only.

Comment: @Narasimham  What do you mean by "default or chosen mesh parameter values "?  For instance, do you mean that you wish to display the values of {v, u} at the closest mesh lines?  Or, do you mean that you wish to see nothing, unless the pointer is precisely on a mesh line?

Comment: Thanks for your sustained interest. It is like in ContourPlot or Manipulate. Mesh gives nmeshx+1, nmeshy+1 values for (u,v), they are sufficient . Too many values on pixel basis not needed to be labeled with Tooltip. For example u (\ cos t , \sin t) some 5 numbers for u and t.

Comment: @Narasimham  Do you wish values of {v, u} to be displayed only at the points where grid lines intersect?

Comment: I have updated my question. Request is for fiduciary Tooltip for two sets of lines.

Comment: Nice approach. Is it possible to avoid the faked ToolTip to be clipped to the graphics boundary when getting near the Plot's border (see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Izsbn.png)) or would this require another approach?

Comment: @Jinxed  I inserted `ImagePadding -> {{60, 90}, {40, 10}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,` for precisely that purpose but did not leave enough space.  Just replace `90` by `100` to eliminating the clipping.  A better solution would have been to move the `Inset` to the other side of the pointer whenever it got close to the right edge of the plot.

Answer (score 4):

In Comments above, the OP requested that values be displayed only for mesh  points.  This can be accomplished as follows, using `Annotation`.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
       FrameLabel -> {Cos[u]^v, u}], 
     ListPlot[Quiet@Table[Annotation[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {N[v], N[u]}, "Mouse"], 
       {v, 0, 1, 1/6}, {u, 0, Pi/2, Pi/12}], PlotStyle -> Black], 
     Epilog -> Inset[Dynamic[Style[MouseAnnotation[], Bold, 14]], {.25, 0}]]
```

The mesh points are generated as a Table (complete with `Annotation`), plotted with `ListPlot`, and superimposed using `Show` on a `ParametricPlot` of the `Mesh`.  The combined plot is shown below, and `Null` is replaced by the values `{v, u}` when the cursor is place on a point.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If, instead, the standard `Tooltip` appearance is desired, one can use

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, Mesh -> {5, 5}, 
       FrameLabel -> {Cos[u]^v, u}], 
     ListPlot[Quiet@Table[Annotation[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {N[v], N[u]}, "Mouse"], 
       {v, 0, 1, 1/6}, {u, 0, Pi/2, Pi/12}], PlotStyle -> Black], 
     ImagePadding -> {{60, 60}, {40, 10}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
     Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style[Dynamic[m], "TooltipLabel"], FrameMargins -> 0, 
       ContentPadding -> False], Dynamic[m = MouseAnnotation[]; 
       If[VectorQ[m], {Cos[Last@m]^First@m, Last@m}, {-20, 0}]], {-1.1, -1.1}]]
```

**Addendum**

Using the second argument of `ToolTip` also works well.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {v, 0, 1}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, 
       Mesh -> {5, 5}, FrameLabel -> {Cos[u]^v, u}], 
     ListPlot[Quiet@Table[Tooltip[{Cos[u]^v, u}, {N[v], N[u]}], {v, 0, 1, 1/6}, 
       {u, 0, Pi/2, Pi/12}], PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]